# How did Mohan Srivastava crack Ontario scratchcards?

Tags: probability, gambling, lotteries

Wired ran a 2011 [article](https://www.wired.com/2011/01/ff_lottery/all/1) about how a statistician, Mohan Srivastava, cracked Ontario scratchcards such as [this one](https://archive.wired.com/magazine/wp-content/images/19-02/ff_lottery4_f.jpg).

First, he thought about the program that produced the numbers on the cards.

> 'Of course, it would be really nice if the computer could just spit out
>   random digits. But that’s not possible, since the lottery corporation
>   needs to control the number of winning tickets. The game can’t be truly
>   random. Instead, it has to generate the illusion of randomness while
>   actually being carefully determined.'

He realised that if a card had a certain feature, it was likely profitable.

> Srivastava was looking for singletons, numbers that appear only a single
>   time on the visible tic-tac-toe boards. He realized that the singletons
>   were almost always repeated under the latex coating. If three singletons
>   appeared in a row on one of the eight boards, that ticket was probably a
>   winner.

**How might a program that produced the numbers work?**

**And how did Srivastava infer that consecutive singletons would be predictive of winning cards?**

Answer (score 1):

*PROBLEMS WITH AN INSTANT SCRATCH LOTTERY GAME: An analysis of why the OLGC’s TicTacToe game was exploitable* helps to answer these questions.

http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~gill/Jul2003_Report_on_TicTacToe.pdf

**How might a program that produced the numbers work?**

The report explains:

> 1. For each card, decide if it is going to be a winner or a loser.
> 2. If it’s going to be a winner, lay down a pattern of X’s and O’s that has the desired
>      alignment of X’s in exactly the correct position. This is easy to do since there are only a
>      few hundred possible arrangments of X’s and O’s; these can be calculated beforehand,
>      stored and then searched for an arrangement that has the X’s in a certain location.
> 3. If it’s going to be a loser, lay down a pattern of X’s and O’s that has no winning
>      alignment in the X’s. As with setting up a winning card with its X’s in exactly
>      the right position, ensuring that there are no winning alignments is a simple task of
>      searching through a precalculated data base of all possible arrangments and selecting
>      from one of the many that have no winning alignments.
> 4. Having fixed the location of the X’s and the O’s, the remaining tasks are to choose 24
>      numbers for the scratch list, assign the X locations numbers from this list and assign
>      the O locations numbers that do not appear on the list.

**And how did Srivastava infer that consecutive singletons would be predictive of winning cards?**

Nothing I could find answers this question, but I assume he came up with the same method of generating the cards, then realized the problem with it.

The report states:

> The heart of the problem, therefore, is that there are far more numbers on the scratch 
>     list than off it (a result, in part, of someone’s decision that the choices should go 
>     from 1 to 39), but the number of cells that need to be populated with numbers from each 
>     group is roughly equal. The consequence of this is that the number of repetitions of a 
>     particular number on the eight playing boards ends up providing clues to whether or not 
>     that number is on the scratch list.